# How can I render inline JavaScript with Jade / Pug?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm trying to get JavaScript to render on my page using Jade (http://jade-lang.com/)

My project is in NodeJS with Express, eveything is working correctly until I want to write some inline JavaScript in the head. Even taking the examples from the Jade docs I can't get it to work what am I missing?

### Jade template

```
!!! 5
html(lang="en")
  head
    title "Test"
    script(type='text/javascript')
      if (10 == 10) {
        alert("working")
      }
  body
```

### Resulting rendered HTML in browser

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>"Test"</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    <if>(10 == 10) {<alert working></alert></if>}
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Somethings definitely a miss here any ideas?

Comment: You're missing a dot `.` after the `(type='text/javascript')`

Comment: `!!! 5` is deprecated, you must use `doctype html`

Answer (score 415):

simply use a 'script' tag with a dot after.

```
script.
  var users = !{JSON.stringify(users).replace(/<\//g, "<\\/")}
```

https://github.com/pugjs/pug/blob/master/packages/pug/examples/dynamicscript.pug

Comment: Good solution, but it will produce only `<script>` instead of `<script type="text/javascript">`.

Comment: `type="text/javascript"` is the default value for the `type` field on `<script>` tags. You don't need to set it.

Comment: What about multiline code? Is there a way to have proper code indentation in my Javascript when embedded in Jade this way?

Comment: Jade's policy changed, the inline script tag should now have a `.` appended.  So `script.` followed by your indented block of JS.

Comment: I don't know about indentation missingfaktor.  Perhaps save your users some bandwidth by sending js-beautify, so you can prettify the code on the client-side.  ;)

Comment: That example is a script injection vulnerability. See https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/1474

Comment: Notably, all your server-side variables are still injectable in the script using `#{var_name}`

Answer (score 119):

The `:javascript` filter was removed in [version 7.0](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/blob/9487595965d0dc292f4d1b48c7e7d30b2ef5a1ce/History.md#070--2011-03-04)

The [docs says](https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html) you should use a `script` tag now, followed by a `.` char and no preceding space.

Example:

```
script.
  if (usingJade)
    console.log('you are awesome')
  else
    console.log('use jade')
```

will be compiled to

```
<script>
  if (usingJade)
    console.log('you are awesome')
  else
    console.log('use jade')
</script>
```

Comment: tag script with a dot after, in all javascript block is there any way that render it without newlines?

Comment: @Joaquinglez not that I know

Answer (score 63):

Use script tag with the type specified, simply include it before the dot:

```
script(type="text/javascript").
  if (10 == 10) {
    alert("working");
  }
```

This will compile to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (10 == 10) {
    alert("working");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: just `script.` would be fine.

Comment: Adding this will have no effect as it is the default value for inline scripts.

Answer (score 33):

No use script tag only.

Solution with `|`:

```
script
  | if (10 == 10) {
  |   alert("working")
  | }
```

Or with a `.`:

```
script.
  if (10 == 10) {
    alert("working")
  }
```

Comment: I recommend `.`. Otherwise you would have to write `|` in each line.

Answer (score 3):

THIRD VERSION OF MY ANSWER:

Here's a multiple line example of inline Jade Javascript.  I don't think you can write it without using a `-`. This is a flash message example that I use in a partial.  Hope this helps!

```
-if(typeof(info) !== 'undefined')
  -if (info)
    - if(info.length){
      ul
        -info.forEach(function(info){
          li= info
      -})
  -}
```

Is the code you're trying to get to compile the code in your question?

If so, you don't need two things: first, you don't need to declare that it's Javascript/a script, you can just started coding after typing `-`; second, after you type `-if` you don't need to type the `{` or  `}` either.  That's what makes Jade pretty sweet.

--------------ORIGINAL ANSWER BELOW ---------------

Try prepending `if` with `-`:

```
-if(10 == 10)
  //do whatever you want here as long as it's indented two spaces from
   the `-` above
```

There are also tons of Jade examples at:

https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/examples/

Comment: Thanks John have used that for the odd single line, however I can't see anyway of doing multiple lines without prepending it with the '-'.

The Jade homepage ([link](http://jade-lang.com/) even has an example of what i'm trying to do, but it won't compile. I'm using the latest release too.

Comment: So you're asking how to have multiple lines of Javascript code below one if?

Comment: @Bluey same here, I've never gotten this to work. You should ask on the github issues.

Comment: Mark, have now moved to using Sam Stephenson's Eco instead of Jade. I was only using jade as a quick UI for testing.

Comment: Jade 0.12.4 allows me to script() without prepending the JS with - below it.

Comment: OP asked how to put inline javascript that would execute on the client side - This creates inline javascript that executes on the *server side* before returning the view to the user.

Answer (score 1):

For multi-line content jade normally uses a "|", however:

> Tags that accept only text such as
>   script, style, and textarea do not
>   need the leading | character

This said, i cannot reproduce the problem you are having. When i paste that code in a jade template, it produces the right output and prompts me with an alert on page-load.

Answer (score 1):

```
script(nonce="some-nonce").
  console.log("test");

//- Workaround
<script nonce="some-nonce">console.log("test");</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:javascript` filter. This will generate a script tag and escape the script contents as CDATA:

```
!!! 5
html(lang="en")
  head
    title "Test"
    :javascript
      if (10 == 10) {
        alert("working")
      }
  body
```

Comment: @aaaidan You're right. It's supported by Scalate (I'm using it here with no problems: https://github.com/cb372/phone-home/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/templates/views/recent-events.jade#L7 ) but it looks like pure Jade doesn't support it, as it's not listed here: https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#features . That's a shame!

Comment: Yeah, would have been nice. As the top answer says, a `script.` works fine, and is legal `!!! 5`