# Duplicate attribute "{" is not allowed in Jade

Tags: html, node.js, express, pug, chartist.js

I'm trying to put a script into jade, but it won't let me use multiple curly braces. Here is the chartist code I am trying to put in jade.

```
body
    h1 Crimes by Category
    .ct-chart
    script(new Chartist.Bar('.ct-chart', {
    labels: ['XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL', 'XXXL'],
    series: [20, 60, 120, 200, 180, 20, 10]
    }, {
    distributeSeries: true
    });)
```

I am getting Duplicate attribute "{" is not allowed. I don't know how to get around this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To insert multi-line javascript in Jade, use the `script.` tag (with the content of the script indented):

```
body
    h1 Crimes by Category
    .ct-chart

      script.
        new Chartist.Bar('.ct-chart', {
        labels: ['XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL', 'XXXL'],
        series: [20, 60, 120, 200, 180, 20, 10]
        }, {
        distributeSeries: true
        });
```

You probably also need to indent `script.` one notch if you want it inside your `.ct-chart div.`

source: [How can I render inline JavaScript with Jade / Pug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858218/how-can-i-render-inline-javascript-with-jade)