# Render dynamic content in Pug template

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, pug

Using NodeJS to build an web app, I am using `React` and `Pug` together. I know that Pug is for rendering static content, and `React` is responsible for rendering dynamic content. I have a page that needs both.

Think about the Instagram web page, it has some static content, but when user scroll down to the bottom, it will load more pictures.

I have a `Pug` template, which in the end, I included the `React` script like this:

```
block scripts
    script(src="/component/design-grid.js" type="module")
```

And I want to trigger my react code by doing(This won't work):

```
script ReactDOM.render(<DesignGrid mainPage={true} category={"daily"} verified={false}/>, document.getElementById("grid-container"));
```

What's the standard way to accomplish something like this?

Comment: Why doesn't it work?  What is the output you are getting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I render inline JavaScript with Jade / Pug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858218/how-can-i-render-inline-javascript-with-jade-pug)