# Call a node function on each page

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have a function to get a value from the database.
I'd like to call that function for every page and retrieve its value.
it's a node function like this:

```
async function getBitcoinPrice() {

    let btcprice = await cryptoPrice.findOne({"pair": 'BTC'});
    if(!btcprice){
        let price = await btcValue({currencyCode: 'EUR'});
        btcprice = await cryptoPrice.findOneAndUpdate({"pair": 'BTC'},{"pair":'BTC','price' : price},{upsert:true,new:true});
        return btcprice.price;
    }


    return btcprice;

}
```

I'd like to load the value on a header div.
I'm using Pug Template

Comment: Have you tried passing the value to pug in any way yet?

Comment: I want to use in each page, I don't want to pass for each route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need to use `$(document).ready` if you are using jQuery. Or you can simply call this method in `script` tag in your layout page. You can also try `window.attachEvent("onload", fn);`

Comment: I need to call a node function

Comment: Node is not a programing language. it is framework. The method you have written I believe it is in javascript, which can be run via browser or NodeJS. If you want to run this method via NodeJS, you will need to host it through a server. You can use vanilla NodeJS hosting using http module or you can use framework like express or restify to do so. Then you can make ajax call to your Nodejs server which may call this method internally.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Node_server_without_framework

Comment: then create route and call that internal route via Ajax, right?

Comment: Yes Exactly @JEFF

Answer (score 0):

using the solution given in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6838680/6904274) . you can add the infromation in every page and then since it is added in the script, all the js function in the page will be able to access it.