# Inline if statement with Pug

Tags: pug

I'm trying to figure out how to do an inline `if` statement:

```
div(class="social-text").
  #[b #{share.title}] #{share.bodyText}
```

In the code above it's possible that `share.title=undefined`. In case it is, I don't want to render a `<b></b>` tag in the resulting `html` but can't figure out how that works in pug.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I render inline JavaScript with Jade / Pug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858218/how-can-i-render-inline-javascript-with-jade-pug)

Comment: @Freestyle09 that's not related to this question

Comment: @Freestyle09 - no, not really. This one is about inline pug, not inline javascript ... :)

Answer (score 1):

This is simpler to write if you don't use the [block in a tag syntax](https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html#block-in-a-tag) after the initial `div`. You could write it like this instead, using a [standard conditional](https://pugjs.org/language/conditionals.html) and [piped text](https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html#piped-text):

```
div.social-text
  if (share.title !== undefined)
    b #{share.title}
  |  #{share.bodyText}
```